# How to generate manifest (List of files with their sizes and count) for a folder in linux

Tags: linux, shell

How to generate manifest containing all files except particular file name in a folder like the fillowing.

Acctual requirement

```
4
issue1425.tgz       3096209598  
issue1426.TGZ       3096209591
issue1427.ZIP       3096209592
issue1428.zip       3096209593
```

=>
total number of files: 4

file name: issue1425.tgz

size of file: 123333

....

im doing Like this

```
ls i2*.* |wc -l >>manifest.txt
vdir i2*.* >>manifest.txt
```

Output in "manifest.txt" from this is

```
4
-rwxr-Sr-t 1 root root 3096209598 2013-03-28 05:46 issue1425.tgz
-rwxrw-r-- 1 root root 3096209591 2013-03-20 06:46 issue1426.TGZ
-rwxr-Sr-t 1 root root 3096209592 2013-03-28 07:46 issue1427.ZIP
-rwxrw-r-- 1 root root 3096209593 2013-03-20 08:46 issue1428.zip
```

does any one has the solution to get my exact requirement:

Edit 2:@jarnbjo your command gives me wrong output see the actual sizes of files but its gives me wrongly.

```
root@aim-deb:/mnt/arch1/batchfiles/siva/20130328094916142/received# vdir
total 108816
drwxrwxrwx 5 1330 sno      4096 2013-03-20 00:30 i23321367
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1330 sno  39934457 2013-03-20 03:20 i23321367.tgz
drwxrwxrwx 5 1330 sno      4096 2013-03-20 00:33 i23321376
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1330 sno  36030069 2013-03-20 03:20 i23321376.tgz
drwxrwxrwx 5 1330 sno      4096 2013-03-20 00:34 i23321436
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1330 sno  35310600 2013-03-20 03:20 i23321436.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       69 2013-03-29 00:57 manifest_QAG.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1330 sno        75 2013-03-20 03:20 manifest.txt
root@aim-deb:/mnt/arch1/batchfiles/siva/20130328094916142/received# ls -1s --    block-size=1 i*.* $dir| awk '{print $2"\t"$1}'
i23321367.tgz   39981056
i23321376.tgz   36073472
i23321436.tgz   35352576
root@aim-deb:/mnt/arch1/batchfiles/siva/20130328094916142/received#
```

Answer:@jarnbjo thanks finally i got it why its happening. block size gives me size if file size on disk not actual size of file. here i want size of file so i can use  vdir i*.* $dir| awk '{print $8"\t"$5}'

Comment: the count part i m getting correctly but i need help at the second part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the amount of files and its size, try with this:

```
ls -1hs $dir
```

- `h` stands for human readable
- `s` stands for size
- `1` (one)just shows the names of files, one on each line.

And if you want it to be first name, then size, use:

```
ls -1hs $dir | awk '{print $2" "$1}'
```

**Edit**
From comments, you want it to have size in bytes, so you can do it like:

```
ls -1s --block-size=1 $dir
```

**Further edit**
If you want the dir not to be displayed, you have to `cd $dir` previously. There are other ways, but this seems to be the cleanest.

```
cd $dir; ls -1s --block-size=1 is*.* | awk '{print $2"\t"$1}'
```

Comment: its giving size in GBs, MBs, KBs but i want in bytes

Comment: OK then you can replace `h` flag for `--block-size=1`.

Comment: Something like `ls -1s --block-size=1 $dir`

Comment: Thanks this is working ls -1s --block-size=1 is*.* $dir| awk '{print $2"\t"$1}'

Comment: i has a one more doubt here this line gives me directory name also how to avoid this i need only file name ls -1s --block-size=1 test/ap*.* $dir| awk '{print $2"\t"$1}'

Comment: The best you can do is to `cd $dir` firstly and then `ls` --> `cd $dir; ls -1s --block-size=1 is*.* | awk '{print $2"\t"$1}'`. Otherwise you will have to go to things like http://superuser.com/questions/209937/run-an-ls-without-getting-the-full-path

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27149/discussion-between-civa-and-fedorqui)